# Laravel how to sign in automatically after checking if user exists

Tags: database, laravel

What is the best practice for this?
I am new to Laravel and installed it with the starter kit breeze. Which came with an authentication module.
Now I made a form which signs you up, but if you account already is registered in the database, then I want to automatically sign in.

On line 45, I try to redirect the request to the AuthenticationController. But it doesn't work like that.

[image]

Comment: Never share the image of the code. Instead, you should share the code just copy-paste the snippet. With an image, it is difficult to understand the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your line, you are just redirecting the user to the login page. If you want to auto-sign if the user exists then you have to run the following code

```
$user = User::where('...')->where('...')->first();

if ($user) {
    Auth::login($user, true);
    return view('dashboard'); // or where do you want to redirect the user after login.
}
```

Comment: Kind of an obvious point here, but don't forget to check that the user provided a valid password somehow before signing them in

Comment: Yes @apokryfos but I really don't know about the business logic behind this. I also thought the same but thanks for mention it.

Comment: Something @seref needs to be aware of

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos , there's safe logic behind this. :)